# How to parse List of maps Json in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

[image][image][image]I have one Json structure with three maps, one is list of products then total and tax. I have to parse this json structure in flutter. I created on model class. Now i am getting the error in type casting.

How to solve this?

JSON Structure:

```
{
  "products" : [
     {                  
       "cart_id": "7",      
     },          
     {                  
       "cart_id": "7",
     }     
  ],
  "total": 100,
  "tax": 100
}
```

Model class :

```
class CartModel {   
    List<Product> produtcts;
    double total;

    CartModel({this.produtcts, this.total});

    factory CartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        var list = json['products'] as List;
        print(list.runtimeType);
        List<Product> products = list.map((i) => 
           Product.fromJson(i)).toList();

        return CartModel(
            produtcts: products, total: json['total'],);
    }
}

class Product {
    String cartId;

    Product({this.cartId,});

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Product(     
            productId: json['cart_id'],
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you error, `Product.fromJson` or `CartModel.fromJson` ?

Comment: The error is in cartmodel : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Answer (score 5):

Instead of casting the products array to a list try using it as an `Iterable`.

For me the following code works (note that the `json.decode(String)` method is imported from the `dart:convert` package):

```
var data = '{"products":[{"cart_id": "7"},{ "cart_id": "7"}], "total": 100, "tax": 100}';
var decoded = json.decode(data);   
var cartModel = CartModel.fromJson(decoded);

class CartModel {   
    List<Product> produtcts;
    int total;

    CartModel({this.produtcts, this.total});

    factory CartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        Iterable list = json['products'];
        print(list.runtimeType);
        List<Product> products = list.map((i) => 
           Product.fromJson(i)).toList();

        return CartModel(
            produtcts: products, total: json['total'],);
    }
}

class Product {
    String productId;

    Product({this.productId,});

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Product(     
            productId: json['cart_id'],
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The same error, _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast.

Comment: @proversion I have updated my answer with an example on how I called the `CartModel.fromJson` method. This code is working fine, just note that I had to correct some syntax errors in your original question (I have also fixed these in the original question).

Comment: final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        final rest = data as List;

        list = rest.map<CartModel>((json) => CartModel.fromJson(json)).toList();

Comment: Did you check the result you received from your backend system (the actual JSON)? Does it contain a value for the array? I have tried using `jsonDecode()` in the above code and works just fine. To me it looks like the json you are trying to parse is slightly different from what you are expecting and thus resulting in the error.

Comment: Map( 3 Items) - 0 -> Products, 1->total , 2 - > tax

Comment: Yes but wat is in `Products`? I am trying to help, but the code above works fine. If you are using the same, the only thing that can be different is the actual JSON.

Comment: its List (3 Items)

Comment: can you provide a more detailed example of the raw json?

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195579/discussion-between-maurits-van-beusekom-and-proversion).

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply :

```
 List<CartModel> list = new List();
  var jsonlist = jsonDecode(yourJsonString) as List;
  jsonlist.forEach((e) {
    list.add(CartModel.fromJson(e));
  });
```